# How to develop an application employing ADFS security? Interested in the DEV phase

Tags: security, active-directory, single-sign-on, adfs, federated-identity

I recently developed a very small application that is secured using Active Directory (Federated Server) [ADFS].  I was the sole developer.  We set up an ADFS server in our DEV environment, and created an entry that was specific for my dev workstation.  When we pushed this to "PROD" we pointed to a different ADFS server where it had an entry for whatever server that application runs on in PROD.

We now want to work on a much bigger application where we have a large team of developers.  Each Developer will of course have their own workstation.  It's not clear to me how to add multiple workstations as valid endpoints in our ADFS machine.

Is there a way to achieve this?  If not, what is considered "best practice" for developing ADFS-secured apps across a whole raft of machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen two approaches:

- Use localhost for Dev. This will work across all PC
- Don't check in the web.config, app.config or whatever. Developers maintain their own entry.

Comment: is there any way to test (dev and test environment) IF ADFS is not available (windows server is not avialble)

Comment: You could have a look at EmbeddedSTS as long as you are happy using WS Fed - https://github.com/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/wiki/embeddedsts